# Retrieving training data after fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm looking to be able to retrieve the data a scikit-learn estimator was trained on (i.e., after fitting).

For example, if I fit a RandomForestClassifier like so:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
train_X = np.asarray([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
train_y = np.asarray([1, 0, 1])
rf.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Is there a way to return my training data and class labels from the estimator?

Something like....

```
rf.X_
>>>array([[0, 1, 0],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [0, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), I don't see anything that would really permit this. But, you could try defining a class like this:

```
class RFClassifierWithData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clf = RandomForestClassifier()
    def fit(self, train_X, train_y):
        self.train_X = train_X
        self.train_y = train_y
        self.clf.fit(self.train_X, self.train_y)
```

Trying it out:

```
>>> model = RFClassifierWithData()
>>> model.fit(train_X, train_y)
>>> model.train_X
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])
>>> model.train_y
array([1, 0, 1])
```

And you can still access the fitted classifier:

```
>>> model.clf
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

Note that this might not be the most safe or robust way of doing this, but it should give you a good place to start. You would likely want to make equal the parameters passed to `__init__` in this class and the parameters in the base `RandomForestClassifier` class.

Edit:

I still think this is a valid option, even if you're trying to get data from a pickled classifier:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.dump(model, 'model.pkl')
same_model = joblib.load('model.pkl')
```

It's all still there:

```
In [19]: same_model.train_X
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])

same_model.train_y
Out[20]: array([1, 0, 1])
In [21]: same_model.clf
Out[21]: 
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I've used your suggestion before, in cases where I needed to make by own classifier.  Unfortunately, it wouldn't work for my current problem.  I need to retrieve data from some old, pickled estimators.

Comment: Saving the data would be pretty wasteful.. (I mean if it is done as the default behavior)

Comment: Well, I don't think there's a way to retrieve data from old, pickled estimators, but in the future what I've provided above satisfies the very simple base case you've given. See above for how easily you can use `sklearn.externals.joblib` for doing this type of work.